# How to test my views function using Django unit testing?

Tags: django, django-unittest

I have a Django app called sample. I need to check a function inside sample app's views.py file. When I try to import the function , I get an error saying sample.views is not a package.
I am trying to import the function like this :
**from sample.views import samplefunc**

What am I doing wrong ? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the name of your base `folder`? or share your project structure.

Comment: My base folder name is djangotemplates.. I have an app inside named sample

Comment: Can you share your structure? only tree view of folder structure?

Comment: Bro.. I just need to test a views function called samplefunc which is inside the views.py of an app called sample.. I want to test that function using Django unit testing.. Can't that be done in an easier way ?

Comment: What do I have to import ? Can you tell me that ?

Comment: It is important to know your folder structure to tell you from what you need to import views file. Also I don't know why you are importing view function generally we can achive this using `self.client.get(reverse('url_name'))`  using URL only, which we define in urls.py file

Comment: Can't we import a function from an app's view directly ?